# Is it possible to use libraries from hook Classes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hooks

I'm using hooks to call a Class that is executed before controllers are called.

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'CargarInformacion',
    'function' => 'obtenerInfo',
    'filename' => 'CargarInformacion.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => ''
    );
```

This is the class

```
class CargarInformacion 
{
    function obtenerInfo()
    {
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $informacion = $ci->db->get('sitio', 1)->row();
    }
}
```

But I always get the same error

> Trying to get property of non-object

I know there are thousands of answers realated but until now I haven't found the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As codeigniter doc provided,

> **pre_controller**
>
> Called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes, routing, and security checks have been
> done.

That's why you can't access the reference of CI superobject in `pre_controller` hook. You can test it by doing like this.

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'CargarInformacion',
    'function' => 'obtenerInfo',
    'filename' => 'CargarInformacion.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => 'pre'
);

$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'CargarInformation',
    'function' => 'obtenerInfo',
    'filename' => 'CargarInformation.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => 'post'
);
```

In CargarInformation.php,

```
class CargarInformation  {
    function __construct($foo = null) {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function obtenerInfo($param)
    {
        echo $param;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->CI);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Therefore, try to use `post_controller_constructor` instead if you want to get access to the reference of CI superobject but before any method of controller calls happening.

Hope it will be useful for you.